# KDP 'changeMedia' not working after 2 count

Tags: html, video-streaming, kaltura

I am using Kaltura HTML5 Video Player in my web page. On end of the video playing next endryId using *changeMedia* event.
Code is:

```
function playerPlayEndHandler(){
   eIdCount++;
   kdp.sendNotification("changeMedia", {'entryId': entryIdArray[eIdCount]});
}
```

Array variable entryIdArray has 4 endry id's. First 2 endry id's only playing. After end of the 2nd media 3rd media is not changed.
Any one suggest for this?

Comment: Can you add a test page?

Comment: That issue occure in Kaltura. Now its solved by them. So it is working fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue occure in Kaltura Player.

Now its solved by Kaltura team. So, now it is working fine.